# How to send HTTP Post request with body content and query param both in Java

Tags: java, json, rest, grizzly

I want to hit an API having url as below

http://xxxxxxxxx:5234/service/index.php?abc=xyz

This API consumes content-type: application/xml,
request method is POST,
I am sending xml body in request and able to fetch it in API as well but I am not able to fetch value of query param "abc". I can't make any change in API because it's a remote API. when I try to hit the API with postman or curl command with same url as above it's working fine and giving me xml response. but through my java code I am not able to hit above url. I can hit only following url http://xxxxxxxxx:5234/service/index.php . Please help

My application is using grizzly HTTP client-server framework. Below is the HTTP request fields I have configured in my JSON file used by application to send request.

```
"dispatch": {
          "type": "HTTP",
          "host": "http://xxxxxxxxx:5234/service/index.php?abc=xyz",
          "method": "POST",
          "connect-timeout": 10,
          "content-key": "content",    //this is request body
          "http-headers": {
               "Authorization": "Basic SUNNU19uZXcgSWNNJDEyMzQ=",
               "Content-Type": "application/xml"
            }
       }
```

Comment: show us your code

Comment: What´s your code so far?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205980/java-sending-http-parameters-via-post-method-easily

Comment: @janith: Thanks for the link, but my problem is that I have request body also, not only query params, In the solutions given in link they are converting the query params in query string and storing it in request body. But I can't alter body content

Comment: within the out put stream you can append parameters and the body content both